# Android Chromecast: Casting local audio file fails

Tags: android, audio, chromecast, google-cast, android-mediasession

I'm trying to cast a local device audio file to the Chromecast device.
I have a URI, for example `content://settings/system/alarm_alert` and when casting it to Chromecast it simply does not work - `RemoteMediaPlayer` returns result of 2100, which means [FAILED](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastStatusCodes#constants). The same approach but with files from the server, for example `http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/Awakening.mp3` returns [SUCCESS](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastStatusCodes#constants).

Audio playback is implemented the same way as in [UAMP sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer).
Is there any way to cast local audio files? I've heard the way with setting up local Android server however this sounds a bit complicated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a local embedded server for streaming local content is the only way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know any sample or open source example for streaming local content using embedded server?

Comment: I don't have ny sample but you should be able to grab one of many small embedded web servers (such as NanoHttpd) and use that to serve your content from your phone.